# How to access the notifyIcon from another class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `notifyIcon` on my **Main** form, and want to set the baloontip from another class. Now I get the following error: `The name 'TaskbarIcon' does not exist in the current context`.

Now this makes sense, since it's not in the scope but how would I still access this? Do I need an interface? According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5647064/659731 I do need one (but it's a textbox) and you can pass a string, while with the baloontip I need to pass more arguments: `ShowBalloonTip(2000, "Nu:", result[0] + " - " + result[1], ToolTipIcon.Info);`

It's declared with `public System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon TaskbarIcon;`

Comment: How/where is TaskbarIcon being declared?

Comment: Can you post the relevant member variable of your `Main` form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a reference to your `Main` form, which would need to be passed to your class (probably in the constructor):

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Form Main { get; set; }

    public MyClass(Form main, ...)
    {
        Main = main;
    }
}
```

Then you'd call the item from your class:

```
private method DoSomething(...)
{
    Main.TaskbarIcon.ShowBalloonTip(...);
}
```

However, as you [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646954/how-to-access-winform-textbox-control-from-another-class/5647064#5647064), it's better to put something between your class and the actual object.

**Edit:**  You could also pass a delegate to invoke that will make the changes for you, or you could pass a reference to the item (again, not recommended).  However, make sure you're doing this all on the same thread.

**Edit2:**  Building on the link, your interface could look like this:

```
interface IYourForm
{
    void ShowBalloonTip(int timeout, string tipTitle, string tipText, ToolTipIcon tipIcon);
}
```

Your form would then implement the interface:

```
class YourForm : Form, IYourForm
```

And the method:

```
public void ShowBalloonTip(int timeout, string tipTitle, string tipText, ToolTipIcon tipIcon)
{
    TaskbarIcon.ShowBalloonTip(timeout, tipTitle, tipText, tipIcon);
}
```

This would then change your DoSomething method to look like this:

```
private method DoSomething(int timeout, string tipTitle, string tipText, ToolTipIcon tipIcon)
{
    Main.ShowBalloonTip(timeout, tipTitle, tipText, tipIcon);
}
```

Again, **make sure this is all on the same thread**.  Otherwise, this needs to be handled differently.

Comment: Could you tell me how I would create such interface which will handle those multiple arguments?

Comment: Thanks, however it throws me the error `Method must have a return type` for

Comment: Sorry, I edited it again, but I guess not before you got to it.  I was missing the **void** on the interface method.

Comment: Cheers, that part works now. However I get one final error, please have a look at http://pastebin.com/t5TDQ54R

Comment: Did you add the property and assign to it in the constructor?  See the first code block in my answer.