# How to interact with textbox control on winform from class?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get a handle to my form's textbox control from a class in the project, similar to this approach:

[How to access Winform textbox control from another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646954/how-to-access-winform-textbox-control-from-another-class)

I just cannot get it to work. Inside my form class I have this:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  id = new InputDevice(Handle, this);
  id.KeyPressed += new InputDevice.DeviceEventHandler(m_KeyPressed);
}

public void UpdateScanCode(string scanCode)
{
     txtScanCode.Text = scanCode;
}
```

Then inside my InputDevice class I have this:

```
Form mainForm;
public InputDevice( IntPtr hwnd, Form frmMain )
{
   ... stuff ...
   mainForm = frmMain;
}
```

...and finally, inside one of my functions:

```
mainForm.Update???
```

Intellisense cannot find the UpdateScanCode function, though it finds lots of other members of Form1. When I try mainForm.UpdateScanCode() it won't compile.

Why won't this work?

Comment: Try creating object of form1 and try accessing then. Like Form1 frmM = new Form1(); frmM.UpdateScanCode();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `InputDevice` class is referencing the base `Form` class, not your `Form1` class that's extending it. So your code compiles, and you can access anything available on the base `Form` class from `InputDevice`, but you can't access anything specific to `Form1`.

Modify your `InputDevice` class to reference `Form1` instead of `Form`.

```
Form1 mainForm;
public InputDevice( IntPtr hwnd, Form1 frmMain )
{
   ... stuff ...
   mainForm = frmMain;
}
```

There may not even be a need to pass the instance of `Form1` to `InputDevice`. If "ScanCode" were a public property on `InputDevice` (with a public "getter" at least), you could just use this code in `Form1` instead:

```
id.KeyPressed += delegate { txtScanCode.Text = id.ScanCode; };
```

Or perhaps the scan code is passed back via the event arguments of that delegate?

```
id.KeyPressed += (s, e) => txtScanCode.Text = e.ScanCode;
```