# access form's text box value from another class in c# in timer

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I want to show DateTime into a text box of a form "Form1".I have created a class "schedule" to create a timer with an interval 1 sec. But  cannot access and update Form1's textbox field "xdatetxt". I cannot understand why is it not accessing the controls xdatetxt in Form1.

```
Schedule.cs

class Schedule{

System.Timers.Timer oTimer = null;
    int interval = 1000;
    public Form anytext_Form;

    public Schedule(Form anytext_form)
    {
        this.anytext_Form = anytext_form;
    }

    public void Start()
    {           
        oTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(interval);
        oTimer.Enabled = true;
        oTimer.AutoReset = true;
        oTimer.Start();
        oTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(oTimer_Elapsed);
    }

    private void oTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {//i want to put here a line like             "anytext_Form.xdatetxt.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();"
    }
}
```

in form1.cs:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeScheduler();
    }
    void InitializeScheduler()
    {
        Schedule objschedule = new Schedule(this);
        objschedule.Start();
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to get the instance of the form that you want to modify the text. You can do it by passing a reference to the objschedule or by using `Application.openforms`.

The first way is perfect if you already have the form referenced but if you don, just:

```
private void oTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic f = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["anytext_Form"];
    f.xdatetxt.Text=System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this SO thread -
[How to access Winform textbox control from another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646954/how-to-access-winform-textbox-control-from-another-class)

1. Basically expose a public property that updates Textbox
2. Make Textbox public

Also note, you need to update Form Controls in UI thread

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here, but both are rather straight-forward to address.

**Problem 1: Referencing the form by its base class**

Your `Schedule` class' constructor takes an instance of `Form`. That is the base class of your `Form1` class, and it has no `xdatetxt` field. Change your `Schedule` constructor to accept and store an instance of `Form1` instead:

```
public Form1 anytext_Form;

public Schedule(Form1 anytext_form)
{
    this.anytext_Form = anytext_form;
}
```

**Problem 2: Updating a control from a non-UI thread**

Once you get the compiler error fixed, you will encounter a runtime error. The reason is that the `Timer` class executes its callback on a background thread. Your callback method attempts to access a UI control from that background thread, and that is not allowed.

I could give a solution inline here, but instead I will point you at another StackOverflow post with far more details about the problem and how to fix it: [Cross-thread operation not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the).

Comment: Boss, I am referencing Form1 class when creating object for schedule class..  Schedule objschedule = new Schedule(this);  I cant write public Schedule(Form1 anytext_form) as Form2 may also be referenced instead of Form1

Comment: xdatetxt field is available in form1.designer.cs                                         private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
        public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox xdatetxt;